Asymptotic order of $\sum_{n>x}\frac{\mu (n)\ln n}{n^2}$
I'm working on this proof:

If $x\geq 2$ prove that $$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\varphi(n)}{n^2}=\frac{C+\ln x}{\zeta(2)}-A+\mathcal{O}\Big(\frac{\ln x}{x}\Big)$$ where $C$ is Euler's constant and
$$A=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\mu (n) \ln n}{n^2}$$

I'm almost done (the text is here just for a bit of context) but I'm stuck with the last step. To complete the proof I should prove that $\sum_{n>x}\frac{\mu (n)\ln n}{n^2}$ is a big oh of order less than (or equal to) $\mathcal{O}\Big(\frac{\ln x}{x}\Big)$. To do this I've tried using the fact that the Moebius function is always $\mu (n)\leq 1$ so
$$\sum_{n>x}\frac{\mu (n)\ln n}{n^2}\leq \sum_{n>x}\frac{\ln n}{n^2} \leq \sum_{n>x}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2} = \sum_{n>x}\frac{1}{n^\frac{3}{2}}$$
This sum converges but I don't know how to evaluate its order. Searching online I found that this may be $\mathcal{O}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\Big)$ but I don't know why.
Can you please help me?

Have you tried to replace the last sum $\sum_{n>x} n^{-3/2}$ with an appropriate integral, say, $\int_x^\infty t^{-3/2} dt$?

Your current bound $\sum_{n>x} n^{-3/2}$ would yield $O(x^{-1/2})$, which goes to $0$ slower than $O(\ln(x)/x)$. But you can get a better bound with a simple trick.
Observe that
$$\left|\sum_{n>x}\frac{\mu(n) \log(n)}{n^2}\right|\le \sum_{n>x} \frac{\log(n)}{n^2} = \sum_{n>x} \int_{n-1}^{n}\frac{\log(n)}{n^2} dt \le \sum_{n>x} \int_{n-1}^{n}\frac{\log(t)}{t^2} dt $$
and
$$\int_{x-1}^\infty \frac{\log(t)}{t^2}dt = \frac{\log(x-1)+1}{x-1} = O\left(\frac{\log(x)}{x}\right).$$
